# Update SET Age in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive

This is just an example , which I encountered while practicing HQL.

How can I update age(currently set as null) of every id for date "1/2/2019" by age+1 from previous date of same ID?

```
Current data:
id  age     load date
101 200     1/1/2019
101 null    1/2/2019
102 225     1/1/2019
102 null    1/2/2019
103 334     1/1/2019
103 null    1/2/2019

Expected result:
id  age     load date
101 200     1/1/2019
101 201     1/2/2019
102 225     1/1/2019
102 226     1/2/2019
103 334     1/1/2019
103 335     1/2/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
update t
set age = (select max(age) + 1 from t t2 where t.id = t2.id  and age is not null ) 
where age is null
  and date = '1/2/2019'
```

Comment: Will this work for partitioned table ? I have a partition on date column